# Swift UI 2 DocumentGroup get navigation bar buttons actions

Tags: swiftui, ios14, documentgroup

[image]

I'm using the new '**DocumentGroup**' Scene for an **iOS 14** (currently working on **Beta**) project and I really don't know how can I detect events in the navigation bar like pressing '<' or back (see screen)of the predefined Navigation bar of the 'DoucmentGroup' Scene. For custom buttons it's possible and it's also not a big deal to change the style of the bar(like gray). I tried to disable the button, adding new buttons to the navigation bar etc. The following example is the standard code when you are going to create a new document based app in Xcode:

```
@main struct DocumentAppApp: App {
@SceneBuilder var body: some Scene {
    
    // Adding of a new document
    DocumentGroup(newDocument: DocumentAppDocuments()) { file in
        ContentView(document: file.$document) // .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}
```

}

```
struct ContentView: View {
@Binding var document: DocumentAppDocuments

var body: some View {
    TextEditor(text: $document.text)
}
```

}

Answer (score 5):

I ended up doing the following in my document's `ContentView.body`:

```swift
        NavigationView {
            SideBar(document: $document)
                .navigationBarItems(leading: Button("Back") {
                    // figure out how to programmatically go back...
                })
            
            Text("Nothing selected")
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
```

I essentially killed the automatic `NavigationView` that comes with the document browser. This is not ideal for many reasons, the first of which is that I haven't actually figured out how to go back just yet. If we had access to the underlying `NavigationView` so i could set up my sidebar and my content, this wouldn't be a problem, but so far I haven't been successful here, either.

`DocumentGroup` kind of seems like half-baked garbage though. Why is it pushing, instead of presenting over an "empty" document? Why can't i set the accent color of the `DocumentGroup`, etc. I've written feedback for these items but who knows if it will get addressed before release.

The last option is to take this over yourself and not use `DocumentGroup` at all, use `UIDocumentBrowserViewController` as a `UIViewControllerRepresentable` and move on with your life. I will probably end up here soon.

UPDATE:
I ditched `DocumentGroup`. It just doesn't make any sense. Pushing the content? Dumb. Changing tint color? Can't. My app has also gotten rid of the SwiftUI app entry so I can fully control the UIDocumentBrowserViewController, and I suggest you do the same. The only tough part was figuring out how to best utilize `UIDocument` based storage instead of the nicer `FileDocument` SwiftUI provides. To do that, I basically did this:

```swift
final class Document: UIDocument, ObservableObject {

   var someDocumentProperty: String = "" {
     willSet {
       // this updates the SwiftUI view hierarchy
       objectWillChange.send()
     } didSet {
       // this will autosave whenever you change this property
       updateChangeCount(.done)
     }
   }
}
```

Now it will fully work with SwiftUI views, save properly, everything.

Answer (score 2):

Exact same problem. In a nutshell, I decided to see if there was still UIApplication.shared being created, and when there was I was able to programmatically go back like so:

```
private func goBack() {
#if canImport(UIKit)
guard let currentWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.first,
      let documentBrowser = currentWindow
      .rootViewController as? UIDocumentBrowserViewController
else
{
  logw(
    "<\(#fileID) \(#function)> Failed to retrieve document browser."
  )
  return
}

documentBrowser.dismiss(animated: true) {
  logi("<\(#fileID) \(#function)> the document browser has dismissed it's child.")
}

#endif
```

}

or simplified:

```
`UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true) { print("the document browser has dismissed it's child.") }`
```

Comment: Thank you! Been looking for a simple answer to this forever, as I'd like to keep the DocumentGroup functionality, but ditch the built in navbar.

Answer (score 0):

My goal is to inject own functionality, while keeping the look and feel of the system back button, provided by the `DocumentGroup`. Please note, that my document view is `UIViewController`, wrapped in `UIViewControllerRepresentable`. The solution, based on Jason Cardwell's:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    var systemBackButtonItem = navigationController?.navigationBar.items?[0].leftBarButtonItems?[0]
    systemBackButtonItem?.target = self
    systemBackButtonItem?.action = #selector(done)
}

@objc private func done() {
    UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true) { 
        print("the document browser has dismissed it's child.") 
    }
}
```

Be cautious though, this might clash with some functionality provided by DocumentGroup. However, so far so good in my case. Another option:

```
    private weak var originalBackButtonTarget: AnyObject?
    private var originalBackButtonAction: Selector?

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        var systemBackButtonItem = navigationController?.navigationBar.items?[0].leftBarButtonItems?[0]
        originalBackButtonTarget = systemBackButtonItem?.target
        systemBackButtonItem?.target = self
        originalBackButtonAction = systemBackButtonItem?.action
        systemBackButtonItem?.action = #selector(done)
    }

    @objc private func done() {
        guard let originalBackButtonAction = originalBackButtonAction else { return }
        originalBackButtonTarget?.perform(originalBackButtonAction, with: self)
    }
```